# How do I fix duplicate values in my primary key?

Tags: excel, database, duplicates, relational-database, primary-key

Complicated question, so bear with me.

So I've been organizing a massive spreadsheet of contact info (35,000 rows) with *tons* of typos, duplicates, incorrect data entry, you name it. I've come surprisingly far in organizing it into a cohesive list by assigning a hash function to first/last name columns, which prevents each duplicate from being listed as unique.

Now, the duplicate rows are not *true* duplicates, meaning they may have the exact same email, name, address, location, etc... but one row contains important information in the "Tags" column, which makes Excel label it as unique. I also do not want that information to be omitted. All of the "duplicates" are some variation of what I just described which prevents me from executing a blanket remove statement. What I want to do is consolidate all of the redundant information from the duplicates into one row, while still retaining any unique info.

Here's the solution I *thought* would work:

> 1. Export entire spreadsheet into Access where I would make the hash function ID my primary key.
> 2. Put each column (phone, email, address, etc...) into separate tables and connect them through
>    the primary key.
> 3. Isolate each table by ID and consolidate duplicate entries by having all information under
>    one parent row

What I now know is that there is a lot wrong with executing this solution, the most glaring issue being that the field I want to assign to primary key has duplicate values, which is the very thing I'm trying to get rid of.

How would I go about consolidating all of these duplicates into one row, without losing any info, and without having to manually go through it all? (Maybe I don't have to use Access at all?)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Vlookup on 35,000 rows would not be terrible, but depends how many "Tags" columns you have. Please tell us more about the information you need retained. So if a person is listed 3 times, could each of the 3 rows have different values in TAGS? Which do you need to keep? So if Tag1 has a value of Ford in one row and Chevy in another row, which do you keep?

Comment: The problem is beyond just the Tags columns; there are duplicates with same name, email, phone number, tags, but different location. And it's one or the other in nearly every single duplicate. The duplicates make up 50% of the spreadsheet. 

Ideally I'd be able to retain all information for each contact (multiple locations, emails, tags, etc...) and have it all linked through the unique ID from the hash function. Whether that's done in Excel or Access doesn't really matter.

Comment: If you want to do this with separate, linked tables, then I'd think Access is the way to go; if you want to do this in Excel, you could probably group the entries by whatever fields result in the data being grouped appropriately, using Power Query.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the reply. If I were to do this through Access, how would I go about making the ID my primary key, even if it has duplicates?



Edit: I think I figured it out; should I just create a table of IDs with the duplicates removed and link it to the the other tables with duplicates?

Comment: Perhaps if you add the `ms-access` tag to your question, someone more knowledgeable than I can help you.  If you want to use Excels's PQ, mock up a data sample (**as TEXT which can be copied**) and try to develop some code based on grouping by the ID code.  Also show a picture of what you would like for results.